# MySQL database changelog (how to make one?)

Tags: php, mysql, logging, phpmyadmin

Hey I was wondering if it was possible to maintain a changelog for a mysql database? I have 6 tables and was wondering if there was an efficient way to make shadow tables for each one that will denote the changes made. Im not sure if I am explaining it well but heres an example:

Action: Table "users" user=john with password = 'password'
Action in background: Table "users_shadow" user=john with password = 'password' action=added

Then if the password changes. The table user only changes the password for that row but the action in background talbe says in new row "users_shadow" user=john with password='password1' action=passwordmodified"

So now I have 2 rows with user john in the shadow table where I can look and see all modifications made to that table.

Sorry, kinda hard to explain, but is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible -- it just requires code.  That said, depending on what you want this for, the [binary logs](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/article.php/3903646/Inside-MySQL-Binary-Logs.htm) may already meet your needs.  Read up on them before you write your own logging code.

Comment: Thanks ill look into that. The thing is that I already wrote 95% of the website and didnt want to go back and add logs to everytime I call the SQL database. I was hoping there was an app for that (lol @ iphone). So I was hoping  there was something DB/Server sided to do it without requiring code modification.